# Can I change this part of the function code?

Tags: sql, case

Good morning, can I be exchanging this part of the code that uses case for a filter? could you help me?

```
(CASE 
     WHEN div.ajuizada_em IS NOT NULL
         THEN REPLACE(ROUND(SUM((deb.valor_principal + deb.valor_multa + deb.valor_juros_atualizado) * 0.1), 2)::text, '.',',')
         ELSE REPLACE(ROUND(SUM((deb.valor_principal + deb.valor_multa + deb.valor_juros_atualizado) * 0.05), 2)::text, '.',',') 
 END) AS valor_encargos,
(CASE 
     WHEN div.ajuizada_em IS NOT NULL
         THEN REPLACE(ROUND(SUM((deb.valor_principal + deb.valor_multa + deb.valor_juros_atualizado) * 0.1), 2)::text, '.',',') 
         ELSE '0' 
 END) AS valor_honorarios,
(CASE 
     WHEN nnt.divida_id IS NULL
         THEN true 
         ELSE false 
  END) AS notificada
```

I had no ideas what to do with this part of the code

Comment: Can you add more context to this question?  Where is this `case` being used?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted seems part of an SQL statement, to place it in the context of an SQL query:

```sql
SELECT
...
(CASE WHEN div.ajuizada_em is not null 
      THEN replace(round(sum((deb.valor_principal + deb.valor_multa + deb.valor_juros_atualizado)*0.1),2)::text, '.',',')
      ELSE replace(round(sum((deb.valor_principal + deb.valor_multa + deb.valor_juros_atualizado)*0.05),2)::text, '.',',') END) as valor_encargos,
(CASE WHEN div.ajuizada_em is not null 
      THEN replace(round(sum((deb.valor_principal + deb.valor_multa + deb.valor_juros_atualizado)*0.1),2)::text, '.',',') 
      ELSE  '0' end) as valor_honorarios,
(CASE WHEN nnt.divida_id is null 
      THEN true 
      ELSE false END) AS notificada
...
FROM ......
```

There are 3 `CASE WHEN` statements and I will (try to ) explain the first.

`CASE WHEN div.ajuizada_em is not null`

When `div.ajuizada_em is not null`

then

`THEN replace(round(sum((deb.valor_principal + deb.valor_multa + deb.valor_juros_atualizado)*0.1),2)::text, '.',',')`

else

`ELSE replace(round(sum((deb.valor_principal + deb.valor_multa + deb.valor_juros_atualizado)*0.05),2)::text, '.',',') END)`

`as valor_encargos`, and name the column `valor_encargos`

More info:

- when this is about MySQL: [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html)
- when this is about MSSQL: [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
- when this is about PostgreSQL: [CASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)